# Is there any performance loss when using an SSD with USB 3.1?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, external-hard-drive, usb-storage, usb-3

I am thinking about saving some money buying a MacBook with less storage and  an external SSD connected through USB 3.1 type-C. I would like to know if there is any performance loss. I will be using it mainly for Windows and Linux virtual machines and media storage.

Comment: Bandwidth is unlikely to be an issue, but latency will. You're introducing additional steps between the data and the device. That said, for low importance systems such as VMs and media storage there isn't likely to be too much issue. If you were building a performance system, you'd want the storage as close to the the heart of the system as possible, but the very fact you're considering budget means this probably isn't going to be a problem for you.

Comment: Why are you buying a Macbook if you are on a budget and mainly wanting to use it for things better suited to a non-mac PC?

Comment: the [enclosure should support UASP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_Attached_SCSI) for the best performance. I also use USB 3.0 with UASP and it runs my VMs fine.

Comment: @davidgo I'm buying a macbook because I use it for iOS development and I prefer the os. I'm not that tight on budget, just not willing to pay $400 for 256gb of additional storage